# C programming. The FizzBuzz program

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

I had a quiz and I wrote this code:

Print Fizz if it is divisible by 3 and it prints Buzz if it is
divisible by 5.  It prints FizzBuss if it is
divisible by both.  Otherwise, it will print the numbers between 1 and 100.

But after I arrived home, I wondered if could have
writen it with less code.  However, I could not come out
with a shorter code.
Can I do it with a shorter code?  Thanks.

This is what I wrote and I think it works well. But can I have done it
with less code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=100; i++)
    {
        if(((i%3)||(i%5))== 0)
            printf("number= %d FizzBuzz\n", i);
        else if((i%3)==0)
            printf("number= %d Fizz\n", i);
        else if((i%5)==0)
            printf("number= %d Buzz\n", i);
        else
            printf("number= %d\n",i);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? (BTW, did you really intend to optimize the first if statement that much? :(

Comment: stack exchange has a codegolf site I do believe

Comment: This question tends to defeat those who try to be clever. You can make it shorter, but then it's easy to get it wrong. What you did is the simple way to get it right.

Comment: No, this is not a homework problem at all.  I just was trying to learn if I could have done it in shorter way.  And I learned something here from the user paxdiable, where if you need to test two conditions, sometimes you could reduce these two conditions to be just one and therefore your code will be shorter.  When I wrote my code I did not think in that way.  Now I will use his technique from now on.

Comment: `if(((i%3)||(i%5))== 0)` Don't try to be too clever, it just obscures what your code is intended to do. Also, it should print Fizz/Buzz *instead* of the number, so beware that some of the solutions given in the answers are wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because review of functional code is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Your question may be on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Totally weird that this was closed imho. How is it possibly not a programming question?

Answer (score 17):

You could also do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=100; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            printf("Fizz");
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            printf("Buzz");
        if ((i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0))
            printf("number=%d", i);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A few lines shorter, and a lot easier to read.

Comment: If you always wan't the number you could also strip a line by doing printf("number=%d ", i) at the top and removing the last if.

Comment: `if ((i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0))` can actually just be written as `if (i % 3 && i % 5)`. `i % 3` and `i % 5` in this case will return non-zero numbers, which evaluate to true.

Comment: Sometimes it isn't easy for people to keep things simple. You did it. +1.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure when you'd start calling it unreadable, but there's this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i = 1;
   for (; i<=100; ++i) {
      printf("number= %d %s%s\n", i, i%3?"":"Fizz", i%5?"":"Buzz");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It runs well, and it's shorter.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure paxdiablo's solution is faster though, and not even that much longer.

Comment: Well, in all honesty, the question did ask for shorter rather than faster :-) If you declared `i` within the `for` statement and ditched the braces, it would be even shorter, without sacrificing readability. +1.

Comment: @paxdiablo I could dispense with the braces, but I'm not sure about the i, since the OP didn't mention if this was C99 or not. There are no hints in the code either.

Comment: It shouldn't print the number when it prints Fizz or Buzz.

Comment: Not the actual solution. You cant print the number before each line.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan I know, but I moulded my answer on the OP's code rather than on description of what the program should do. The question was how to make their code shorter, not how to implement FizzBuzz correctly!

Answer (score 8):

If a number is divisible by both 3 and 5, then it's divisible by 15, so:

```
for each number 1 to 100:
    if number % 15 == 0:
        print number, "fizzbuzz"
    else if number % 5 == 0:
        print number, "buzz"
    else if number % 3 == 0:
        print number, "fizz"
    else:
        print number
```

Other than that, you probably won't get it much shorter, at least in a conventional language like C (and I'm assuming you don't want the normal code-golf style modifications that make your code unreadable).

You could also get the whole thing into two lines if you packed the entire `main` function onto a single large line, but I would hope you wouldn't be after that sort of trickery either.

You can possibly get it *faster* (though you should check all performance claims for yourself) with something like:

```
static const char *xyzzy[] = {
    "",     "",     "fizz", "",     "buzz",
    "fizz", "",     "",     "fizz", "buzz",
    "",     "fizz", "",     "buzz", "fizzbuzz",
    // Duplicate those last three lines to have seven copies (7x15=105).
};
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    printf ("%d %s\n", i, xyzzy[i-1]);
```

As an aside, that array of char pointers is likely to be less space-expensive than you think, thanks to constant amalgamation - in other words, it will be likely that there will only be *one* of each C string.

As I say, whether it's faster should be tested. In addition, your original specs only called for the shortest code so it may be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. That's true. For the first test I could think of it in term of just one number.  I will take that into account with future exercises.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that modulo is expensive while comparisons are cheap so only perform the modulo once. That would yield something like this.

```
int i;
for( i = 0; i!=100; ++i ) {
    bool bModThree = !(i % 3);
    bool bModFive = !(i % 5);

    if( bModThree || bModFive ) {
        if( bModThree ) {
            printf( "Fizz" );
        }
        if( bModFive ) {
            printf( "Buzz" );
        }
    } else {
        printf( "%d", i );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to always print the number.

Comment: @franklynd Oh damn. You're right. I updated the answer with a better example.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char const * template[] = {
  "%i",
  "Buzz",
  "Fizz",
  "FizzBuzz"
};
const int __donotuseme3[] = { 2, 0, 0 };
const int __donotuseme5[] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
#define TEMPLATE(x) (template[__donotuseme3[(x) % 3] | __donotuseme5[(x) % 5]])

int
main(void) {
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    printf(TEMPLATE(i), i);
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like that solution for it's creativity. :)

Answer (score 2):

This one avoids some code repetition but requires a temporary variable `char t`

```
void FizzBuzz( ) {
    char t = 0;
    for (unsigned char i = 1; i <= 100; ++i, t = 2) {
        (i % 3) ? --t : printf("Fizz");
        (i % 5) ? --t : printf("Buzz");
        if (!t) printf("%d", i);
        printf("\n");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would write something like that

```
    main(){
  if (i % 3 == 0){
  cout<<"Fizz";
  }
  if (i % 5 == 0){
  cout<<"Buzz";
  }
  // So if both are true, it will print “FizzBuzz” and augment the two strings
    }
```

Comment: You're not printing the number.

Comment: This question was about C programming, not C++ programming, so this solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a helper function :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fbindex(int n) {
    int i = 0;
    if (n % 3 == 0) i += 1;
    if (n % 5 == 0) i += 2;
    return i;
}

int main(void) {                                 
    const char *fb[] = {"%d\n", "Fizz\n", "Buzz\n", "FizzBuzz\n"};
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) printf(fb[fbindex(i)], i);                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char h[4];

    while (++i <= 100)
    {
        sprintf(h, "%d", i);
        printf("%s%s%s\n", i%3 ? "" : "fizz", i%5 ? "" : "buzz", (i%3 && i%5) ? h: "");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a String:

```
String s="";
if(num%3==0)
   s+="fizz";
if(num%5==0)
   s+="buzz";
if(s.length()==0)
   s+=num+"";
```

Comment: Please edit your post so that your text is not formatted as code.

Comment: In plain C there is no type called "String". There's `std::string` (lowercase!) in C++, but this question is tagged C.

Comment: I'm just focusing on the algo . I hope you can get that !

Comment: It reduces the 4 used if else condition to just 3 . time taken for 100 numbers in the given answer is 12 milli sec and mine is 6 milli sec . That's half the time taken

Comment: Can be done with a char array as well and using `stract` instead to make it `c`.

Answer (score -2):

**Obfuscated** form of Mr Lister's answer

`main(int i){while(i++<100){printf("number= %d %s%s",i,i%3?"":"Fizz",i%5?"":"Buzz");}}`

Comment: This is not obfuscated (removing line breaks is hardly obfuscation), it is wrong.